# Were the reference ranges of liver function tests set three times higher than their usual values during the research on the use of statins?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine, cholesterol

I am now holding a book called "The Hidden Therapies - What your doctor won't tell you" authored by Jerzy Zięba, who is widely considered to be a quack by medical authorities in my country. Nevertheless, the sheer amount of facts (or "facts"?) and research papers cited by Mr. Zięba warrants some closer skeptical attention.

Among many other claims Mr. Zięba says that during the clinical research on statins the reference ranges of liver function tests were falsified: in particular, they were set up to three times higher in comparison with their usual values Mr. Zięba cites a book by Dr. Uffe Ravnskov called "The Cholesterol Myths". A copy of this book was supposedly literally burned during a TV program in Yle TV1. According to Mr. Zięba this happened because the medical community was infuriated by the outstandingly documented facts present in this book and their inability to argue against it. Mr. Zięba argues that because of this falsification statins are incorrectly believed to be safe among physicians.

Did Uffe Ravnskov claim that the reference ranges of liver functions were falsified in the aforementioned way during the research on statins?

Does Mr. Ravnskov's book indeed prove this falsification?

The aforementioned claims come from: Ukryte Terapie - Czego lekarz ci nie powie by Jerzy Zięba, vol. 2, pages 107-112.